# MySQL SELECT query with LIMIT to show a maximum of 3 images

Tags: php, mysql, jdatabase

I want to show up to 3 images that are assigned to the logged in user in a database table. I have written the following MySQL query:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    //GET GALLEERY IMAGES
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__mcloud_mgallery');
    $query->where('model_id = '.$userid);
    $query->order('id');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObject();

    $gallery_img = $rows->file;
```

If I echo `$gallery_img` this outputs only one of the images, if I look in the database table (for the logged in user) there are 3 images assigned to that user:

```
id      file                    model_id

389     10_burgers_food.jpeg    941
390     14_bridge.jpeg          941
391     test_imag.jpeg          941
```

How can I show the 3 images if there's only 1 variable `$gallery_img`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem being is you're using `loadObject()` which will only ever return 1 result. If you want multiple, you'll need to use `loadObjectList()`, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
      ->from($db->qn('#__mcloud_mgallery'))
      ->where($db->qn('model_id') . ' = ' . $userid)
      ->order('id');
$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<p>' . $row->file . '</p>';
}
```

Just incase there will ever be more than 3 images in the database, you can also limit the results in the query to 3, like so:

```
$query->select('*')
      ->from($db->qn('#__mcloud_mgallery'))
      ->where($db->qn('model_id') . ' = ' . $userid)
      ->order('id')
      ->setLimit('3'); // <-- Here
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Hope this helps